# Change saved image's name

Tags: php, wordpress

Let me quickly explain my problem.
I'm writing a function in javascript to avoid extra bandwidth in my responsive wordpress theme. So basically I'll switch the src for an array of images based on the user's screen resolution.
What I need is a "certain" name for each case.

Like so:

```
if if (wWidth > 769) ---> imagename-desktop.jpg
else if (wWidth <= 768 && wWidth>= 481) ---> imagename-ipad.jpg
else if (wWidth <= 480) ---> imagename-iphone.jpg
```

Actually what I have now is something like

```
imagename-768x300.jpg
imagename-480x200.jpg
imagename-1300x500.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 0):

See this example.

```
<?php 
$path = "D:/x"; 
$dh = opendir($path); 

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) { 
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
        $imageNameAR = explode("-",$file);
        $imageName = $imageNameAR[0];
        $imageLast =  $imageNameAR[1];
        switch($imageLast)
        {
            case "768x300.jpg":
            {
                $newName = $imageName . "-iphone.jpg";
                rename($path."/".$file, $path."/".$newName); 
                break;
            }           
            case "480x200.jpg":
            {
                $newName = $imageName . "-ipad.jpg";
                rename($path."/".$file, $path."/".$newName); 
                break;
            }
            case "1300x500.jpg":
            {
                $newName = $imageName . "-desktop.jpg";
                rename($path."/".$file, $path."/".$newName); 
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
} 
closedir($dh); 
?>
```